# Why can't I retrieve some cookies in Selenium Chrome using get_cookies()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I've encountered an issue with Selenium and Chrome where I'm unable to retrieve all the cookies. I've tried the following methods:

- Opening the browser through VNC and copying the request as cUrl (not all cookies are present in the copied request, while it works fine in regular Safari and Chrome).
- Using the `driver.get_cookies()` method.
- Using `selenium-wire` to intercept the needed request.

Could someone explain why this works for a regular browser but doesn't work for Selenium?

```py
len(intercepted_request.headers['cookie'].split('; '))
# 26
len(driver.get_cookies())
# 26
```

When I try to copy request as cUrl and get cookies from copied value it work. But only for simple browser, not for Selenium Chrome or Chromium

```py
len(copied_cookies.split('; '))
# 31
```

Comment: you should show your Selenium code here.   I'm guessing that either you aren't at the right domain when you call get_cookies() or they are set as http-only.